# How to call a constructor method of Parent class from child prototype in javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Below is the code snippet, where I have defined 'run' method in the constructor unlike 'eat' method which is defined in the prototype. How can i access this 'run' method from B1's prototype which is inherited from A1. My intension is to override 'run' method in B1 where I can use existing 'run' method of A1. Is there any way to achieve it?

```js
function A1() {
 this.run = function() {
  return 'A1 runs';
 }
};
A1.prototype.eat = function() {
 return 'A1 eats';
};

function B1() {
 A1.call(this);
};
B1.prototype = Object.create(A1.prototype); //new A1();

B1.prototype.eat = function() {
 return A1.prototype.eat.call(this) + ',B1 also eats'; 
}

B1.prototype.run = function() {
 var parentRun = this.constructor.run();
  var result = parentRun + ",B1 also runs";
  return result; 
};


var b1 = new B1();
b1.eat(); // It will give 'A1 eats, B1 also eats', which is fine
b1.run(); // It will give 'A1 runs', where I want 'A1 runs, B1 also runs'.
```

**Edit 1:**
I have updated the code snippet, i have removed the console.log and returned the string from each method.

Initially i did not put my research about this. A few people have mentioned it duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854958/how-to-call-a-parent-method-from-child-class-in-javascript), I had gone through the same link but my question is totally different. I know how to call a method of Parent class's prototype which I have done for "eat".

My query is simple,
**is there any way to access the methods of Parent class's constructor ('run' method), not the method of prototype ('eat' method)?**

Comment: you do not return anything from `A1.prototype.run` for it to be concatenated and you don't execute `console.log` of the result of string concatenation from `B1.prototype.run`

Comment: @Aprillion Please see the Edit1. Let me know if I am still making a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three issues:

1. The `run` that `A1` puts on instances doesn't return anything, so calling it yields `undefined`.
2. `A1` puts `run` on the *instance*, which means that in your `b1` instance, `B1.prototype.run` has been obscured by the `run` that `A1` assigned directly to the instance.
3. `this.constructor.run()` isn't how you would call the `A1` version.

If you put `run` on `A1.prototype`, you can do it:

```
function A1() {
}
A1.prototype.eat = function() {
    console.log('A1 eats');
};
A1.prototype.run = function() {
    return 'A1 runs';
};

function B1() {
    A1.call(this);
}
B1.prototype = Object.create(A1.prototype);

B1.prototype.run = function() {
    return A1.prototype.run.call(this) + ",B1 also runs";
};
var b1 = new B1();
console.log(b1.run());
```

That's ugly, which is why [I wrote a script to automate supercalls back in the day](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lineagejs/), but it's how you do it when working at this level.

These days, though, you'd use ES2015's `class` syntax and `super` instead, transpiling with [Babel](https://babeljs.io) or [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) or similar if necessary to support obsolete JavaScript engines:

```js
class A1 {
    eat() {
        console.log("A1 eats");
    }
    run() {
        return "A1 runs";
    }
}

class B1 extends A1 {
    run() {
        return super.run() + ",B1 also runs";
    }
}

var b1 = new B1();
console.log(b1.run());
```

---

Re your edit saying you **don't** want `run` to be on the prototype, that it has to be assigned by `A1` like this:

```
function A1() {
    this.run = function() {
        return 'A1 runs';
    };
}
```

That's a bit more of a hassle, but you can still do it. For the reason I stated above, setting `run` on the instance will obscure the `B1.prototype.run` that your instance would normally use. So to use that, but also call `A1`'s **non-prototype** `run`, you have to replace it on the instance.

For that reason, it would make sense to define `B1`'s `run` in `B1` rathr than on `B1.prototype`, just like `A1` defines it in `A1`, not on `A1.prototype`:

```
function B1() {
    var A1run;
    A1.call(this);
    A1run = this.run;
    this.run = function() {
        return A1run.call(this) + ",B1 also runs";
    };
}
```

Live example:

```js
function A1() {
    this.run = function() {
        return 'A1 runs';
    };
}
A1.prototype.eat = function() {
    console.log('A1 eats');
};

function B1() {
    var A1run;
    A1.call(this);
    A1run = this.run;
    this.run = function() {
        return A1run.call(this) + ",B1 also runs";
    };
}
B1.prototype = Object.create(A1.prototype);

var b1 = new B1();
console.log(b1.run());
```

But if you really, really want it to be (at least partially) on `B1.prototype`:

```
function B1() {
    var A1run;
    A1.call(this);
    A1run = this.run;
    this.run = function() {
      return A1run.call(this) + B1.prototype.run.call(this);
    };
}
// ...
B1.prototype.run = function() {
    return ",B1 also runs";
};
```

Live example:

```js
function A1() {
    this.run = function() {
        return 'A1 runs';
    };
}
A1.prototype.eat = function() {
    console.log('A1 eats');
};

function B1() {
    var A1run;
    A1.call(this);
    A1run = this.run;
    this.run = function() {
        return A1run.call(this) + B1.prototype.run.call(this);
    };
}
B1.prototype = Object.create(A1.prototype);

B1.prototype.run = function() {
    return ",B1 also runs";
};
var b1 = new B1();
console.log(b1.run());
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution using 'class', but currently I am not looking for the ES6 or something that will be compatible to 'class'. I have edited my snippet too to clarify my query. Could you please help me with that!

Comment: @DebajitMajumder: If you need `A1` to put `run` on the instance directly instead of via a prototype, then you have to overwrite it in `B1`. I've added to the answer to show how.

Comment: @t-j-crowder : Awesome, Thanks. :)  

One more query:  

Though I agree with this - "_it would make sense to define B1's run in B1 rathr than on B1.prototype, just like A1 defines it in A1, not on A1.prototype_", but is there any way to access/call the A1's run method from B1's prototype directly instead of defining it in the B1's constructor!

Comment: @DebajitMajumder: Not in `B1.prototype.run`, because `b1.run()` calls the `run` that A1 put on the instance directly. The only chance B1 has to intervene is in the B1 function itself, during construction. Remember that "own" properties trump inherited properties.

Comment: @t-j-crowder: Oh yes, got it. Thanks for in-depth explanation.