# Javascript Inheritance Objects

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance, polymorphism

I have this hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Foo {};
public class A extends Foo {};
public class B extends Foo {};
```

I want to model this hierarchy in javascript. So I've tried something like this:

```
var Foo = function () {
  this.doSomething = function(input) {
    //do something
  }
};

var A = function() {
  Foo.call(this);

  this.AdoSomething = function(input) {
    this.doSomething();
    //do more things
  }
}

var B = function() {
  Foo.call(this);

  this.BdoSomething = function(input) {
    this.doSomething();
    //do more things
  }
}
```

And I setup the hierarchy like this:

```
var tempFoo;
if (type === 'A') {
    A.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
    tempFoo = new A();
    tempFoo.AdoSomething(data);
} else {
    B.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
    tempFoo = new B();
    tempFoo.BdoSomething(data);
}
```

This works just fine. But I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this. I would like the javascript objects to look like so:

```
var Foo = function () {
  this.doSomething = function(input) {
    //do something
  }
};

var A = function() {
  Foo.call(this);

  this.doSomething = function(input) {
    //call Foo's doSomething, super.doSomething()
    //do more things
  }
}

var B = function() {
  Foo.call(this);

  this.doSomething = function(input) {
    //call Foo's doSomething, super.doSomething()
    //do more things
  }
}
```

But I can't use `super` or `class` because it's not supported in IE. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854958/how-to-call-a-parent-method-from-child-class-in-javascript) to try to call the parent method (Foo's dosomething) like so:

```
Foo.prototype.doSomething.call(this)
```

But this didn't work. I got an error saying cannot read property call of undefined.

What is the best way to setup the hierarchy in javascript?

Comment: You assigned the function to `this.doSomething`, not `this.prototype.doSomething`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't put the `doSomething` method in `Foo.prototype`, you put it directly in each `Foo` object. You should define it as:

```
var Foo = function() {
    // Foo constuctor code here
};
Foo.prototype = {
    doSomething: function(input) {
        console.log("doSomething: ", input);
    }
}
```

You can even see this in the definition in the question you linked to, in its definition of `myMethod`.