# Call parent function in parent class instead of child (same names) javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have two functions with same names. One inside child class and one inside parent.

I thought If i call method in parent class that parent's function will be invoked.

But it looks it doesn't work like this and invokes child function.

So my question is how to invoke parent function in parent class if i have another with same name in child class.

I would like to get 'Parent' and 'Child', but i get 2 times 'Child'

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.init()
  }
  init() {
    console.log('Parent');
  }
}
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.init()
  }
  init() {
    console.log('Child');
  }
}
new Child();
```

Comment: [How to call a parent method from child class in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11854958/691711)

Comment: Try `super.init();`

Comment: I don't want to invoke parent function in children class but parent function in parent class

Comment: Someone can correct me if I am wrong,  but your ```init()``` from the ```Parent``` class is overridden by you defining ```init()``` in the ```Child``` class.

Comment: More information can be found [here. (under The Third Behavior section)](https://www.educba.com/overriding-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is referring to the child instance, and inherits its `.init` method that shadows the `.init` method inherited from the parent. To refer to that explicitly, you'd write

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    Parent.prototype.init.call(this)
  }
  init() {
    console.log('Parent');
  }
}
```

But this is a really bad idea, both [to override a method where the overriding one shouldn't be called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and in general [to call overrideable methods in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821096/1048572). In your case, just do all your work inside your `constructor` instead and drop the `init` method altogether.

Answer (score 0):

As parent constructor call `init()` already, child constructor should not call `init()` any more.

Instead, child `init()` can optionally call parent `init()`.