# How to avoid inherited methods in call by super constructor keyword

Tags: javascript

I have extended class from `Map`:

```js
class ModifiedMap extends Map {
  constructor(arg) {
    super(arg);
  }
  set(key, value) {
    console.log("doing some work here")
  }
}
```

And if I try to create `ModifiedMap`, I see "doing some work here" printing `n` times (depends on iterator).

```js
new ModifiedMap([["a", "apple"],["b", "orange"],["c", "banana"]])
```

How can I avoid using my subclass's `set` method in the internal algorithm of constructing `Map`? Sure I could rename from set to any name, but I want to know is it possible use the same name?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Your instance will have one method called `set`. It can either be the original, or your overridden one if you override it. It cannot have two `set` methods, one original and yours, and magically use "the right one".

Comment: @deceze - The question isn't unclear. The OP wants the super version of `set` called from the constructor, but their own version called otherwise.

Comment: Why was this question closed? I think it adequately states a problem within object-oriented programming.

Comment: Shouldn't the question at least be *"How can I avoid __the parent using an overridden__ method in its internal algorithm of constructing Map?"* — That sentence as is doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @MaximPro - Just set a flag on the instance at the end of the constructor. In `set`, if the flag isn't set, do `return super.set(key, value);`. Otherwise, do your custom code. But why would you want to avoid the customized `set` behavior during construction?

Comment: @deceze - They should have said "subclass method" instead of "inherited method," but again, the question overall is clear despite that mistake.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59936485/476

Comment: @deceze - Not really. It's the `Map` constructor that's doing the calls to `set`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, but the "this is a really bad idea" part is very relevant.

Comment: @MaximPro - I did some minor cleanup on the question, and in particular updated the last sentence. If I got that wrong, please just edit to fix it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a flag to tell your subclass `set` whether the instance construction is complete, then check that flag in `set`. If the flag isn't set, pass the call on to `super.set`:

```js
class ModifiedMap extends Map {
    constructor(arg) {
        super(arg);
        this.ready = true;
    }
    set(key, value) {
        if (this.ready) {
            console.log("doing some work here");
        } else {
            return super.set(key, value);
        }
    }
}

console.log("Constructing...");
const map = new ModifiedMap([["a", "apple"],["b", "orange"],["c", "banana"]]);
console.log("Done constructing, adding an entry");
map.set("x", "y");
```

---

That said, it seems fairly odd to bypass your subclass's customized `set` only during construction. A separate method specific to the subclass may be a better idea.

Comment: This is overly complicated for something as simple as simply replacing the set method after instanciation.

Comment: Interesting solution! It's not strange to bypass. I define method `set` for my inherited class, Map has the same method in prototype and when we constructing using the `super` keyword, algorithm that covers under `super` uses defined method in inherited class.

In my inherited class I want let to use redefined `set`, but not the parent `set` from Map. I think, I expressed clear.

Comment: Before we can use `this` in consructor of inherited class, we must invoke `super`... on some stage of performing will create `thisArgument` this entity will consist from all inherited methods. So before the calling Map constructor, identifier `this` will be bound with `thisArgument` that already has inherited method `set`. When inside `super` will occur the invocation of Map constructor, [algorithm of Map on stage 5](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-map-iterable) take `set` method from our `this` that already has inherited `set`. This is nature of `super` and I can't do anything with this.

Comment: @MaximPro - I understand all of that. I still think it's odd, but of course I don't have the full picture. Did you have a question about the solution, or...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wrote this all that you understood that I know how it is inside. I find your solution is neat, so with the most probably I'll use your proposition. Also I find strange decision in ecmascript in relation with `super` behavior when the base function constructor has `this` with inherited properties. It's weird personally for me.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of @T.J.Crowder's solution is to add the flag to the overriden method. Internal calls will not provide this flag, but your custom calls can pass it conditionally.

```js
class ModifiedMap extends Map {
    set(key, value, dowork) {
        if (dowork !== undefined) {
            console.log("doing some work here");
        } else {
            return super.set(key, value);
        }
    }
}

console.log("Constructing...");
const map = new ModifiedMap([["a", "apple"],["b", "orange"],["c", "banana"]]);
console.log("Done constructing, adding an entry");
map.set("x", "y", true);  // <-- pass something when calling set
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget that this is JavaScript and that classes are just glorified factories: everything that is available to objects is available to instances created by classes.

So, just override the method, which is the canonical way to do what you want:

```js
class ModifiedMap extends Map {
    constructor(arg) {
        super(arg);
        
        this.set = (key, value) => {
            console.log("doing some work here", key, value);
        }
    }
}

const map = new ModifiedMap([['foo', 'bar']]);

map.set('oof', 'bar');
```

### More rational

Something was lost in the last few years about JavaScript, and it was lost exactly when classes were added to the language: JavaScript is an Object Oriented language since day one, and everything that OO allows is still available today.

Would `Map` be instanciable using a factory instead of a class, you would not ask yourself "how can I override `set` after instanciation" because it would be totally organic:

```js
// this is the canonical factory for Map
const createMap = (values) => {
  const container = {};

  const map = {
    set: (key, value) => {
      console.log('Canonical set executed with', key, value);
      
      container[key] = value;
    }
  };

  for (const value of values) {
    map.set(value[0], value[1]);
  }

  return map;
}

const baseMap = createMap([['fruit', 'apple'], ['vegetable', 'carrot'], ['animal', 'dog']]);

baseMap.set('foo', 'bar');

const createCustomMap = (values) => {
  const container = {};

  const map = createMap(values);

  map.set = (key, value) => {
    console.log('Custom set executed with', key, value);
  };

  return map;
};

const customMap = createCustomMap([['fruit', 'apple'], ['vegetable', 'carrot'], ['animal', 'dog']]);

customMap.set('foo', 'bar');
```

This snippet is strictly analogous to what you want to achieve and is basically what classes abstract. But, as you can see, you would naturally have overriden `set` using `map.set =` with this approach, and it would have worked immediately.

I have the feeling that classes have made most of us forget about the basis and that, for all the goods they provide, they also made a few things more complicated and less obvious that than the pure form of Object Oriented programming that functional programming brings.

Comment: I thought about this solution, but I don't like that we should define method `set` over and over again.

Comment: What do you mean, again and again? Do you mean at each instanciation?

Comment: You guessed right

Comment: "*classes are just glorified factories*" - no, a class consists not only of a factory function, it mostly consists of a prototype object.

"*just override the method, which is the canonical way to do what you want*" - assigning to the property in the constructor is **not** the canonical way to override a method. That is done by shadowing the inherited method on the prototype object.

Comment: In its purest form, overriding a method is the canonical way to do it. Prototyping is another way, more advanced and less generic.

Comment: @MaximPro well I think you might want to check if defining the method again and again is more or less time and memory consuming than adding branch logic (the `if` of the answer that gets the most vote) to the set method or adding another method. I'm sure the answer is less obvious than you think.

Comment: @EricMORAND overall decision with `if` very neat, but I don't like classes when I have to do extra fields to control some stuff it is annoying. But really I want to throw all to the heck and realize my inherited class in old-fashion style without strange or controversial stuff in code :D

Answer (score -1):

You can inject another class with such tricky methods in the constructor:

```js
class ModifiedMapOverrides extends Map{
  set(...args){
    console.log("doing some work here");
    return super.set(...args);
  }
}

class ModifiedMap extends Map {
  
  constructor(...args){
    super(...args);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, ModifiedMapOverrides.prototype);
  }

}


console.log("Constructing...");
const map = new ModifiedMap([["a", "apple"],["b", "orange"],["c", "banana"]]);
console.log("Done constructing, adding an entry");
map.set("x", "y");

console.log(JSON.stringify([...map]));
```

You can use an anonymous class also:

```js
class ModifiedMap extends Map {
  
  constructor(...args){
    super(...args);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, (class extends Map{
      set(...args){
        console.log("doing some work here");
        return super.set(...args);
      }
    }).prototype);
  }

}


console.log("Constructing...");
const map = new ModifiedMap([["a", "apple"],["b", "orange"],["c", "banana"]]);
console.log("Done constructing, adding an entry");
map.set("x", "y");

console.log(JSON.stringify([...map]));
```