# TypeScript call base class function from within extended class function override

Tags: typescript, extends, base-class

If I have an extended class that overrides a base class function, can I call the base class function within the extended class function? Something similar to:

```
class Base {

  DoSomething() {

    console.log("base class function");

  }

}

class Derived extends Base {

  DoSomething() {

    this.base.DoSomething();

    console.log("extended class function");

  }

}
```

The output from Derived.DoSomething() would ideally look like:

```
"base class function"
"extended class function"
```

Is this possible in TypeScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a parent method from child class in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854958/how-to-call-a-parent-method-from-child-class-in-javascript)

Comment: The second answer to that question is what I was looking for, thanks! I skipped that post at first because the question looked sufficiently different from what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can access the parent methods via [super keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)

```js
class Base {
  foo() {
    console.log("base class function");
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  foo() {
    super.foo();
    console.log("extended class function");
  }
}

(new Derived()).foo()
```

Comment: foo should be static I think

Comment: @wael32gh For this example static would make sense, however the `console.log` is just a placeholder for more complex logic, which may require it to be non-static by accessing properties of the class instance